# Cipher usage by end users and browsers

Tags: encryption

How do I check in apache logs as to what cipher end users / browsers are using ? Are there other tools to achieve the same to get a result in percentage ?

related link: [How can I determine the encryption strength of an SSL connection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5607/how-can-i-determine-the-encryption-strength-of-an-ssl-connection/5620#5620)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible. What you need is to define the proper configuration setting in `ssl.conf` file for your Apache web server.

An example of which is:

```
  CustomLog logs/access_log \
          "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}t %{Host}i %{User-Agent}i %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x"
```

where the parameter `%{SSL_CIPHER}x` displays the cipher that is being used.

A sample output would be something like this:

```
2015-07-10 23:39 localhost Mozilla/5.0 (some bot) TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

More information could be found on the documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog